# Android, Opengl, GENLOCK_IOC_DREADLOCK failed (lockType0x1,err=Connection timed out fd=59) when call GLSurfaceView onPause

Tags: android, opengl-es

I try to write a android game by opengl es 2.0. I call `GLSurfaceView::onPause` for pausing opengl render thread, not when the activity pauses. On rare occasion, it will happen when call `GLSurfaceView::onPause` as follow:

> 11-17 18:21:16.797: E/libgenlock(6963): perform_lock_unlock_operation:
>   GENLOCK_IOC_DREADLOCK failed (lockType0x1,err=Connection timed out
>   fd=59) 
>   11-17 18:21:16.797: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6963): : 
>   genlock_lock_buffer GENLOCK_WRITE_LOCK failed
>   11-17 18:21:16.797: W/Adreno200-ES20(6963): :
>   GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
>   11-17 18:21:16.797: W/Adreno200-EGL(6963):
>   : EGL_BAD_ALLOC
>   11-17 18:21:16.797:
>   W/GLThread(6963): eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Is there something wrong I use `GLSurfaceView::onPause`?

Comment: At the time you are calling onPause()... are You using the GLSurfaceView in the other thread? If so, You should stop before calling GLSurfaceView::onPause, or call setPreserveEGLContextOnPause (from API 11) to not scrap Your GL contexts on app pause.

Comment: Only Android UI thread use the GLSurfaceView, and I call GLSurfaceView::onPause in this UI thread. I call GLSurfaceView::onPause just for pausing gl render thread, Weather is should call setPreserveEGLContextOnPause?